# Writing labels & data to a CSV file for face recognition. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, pca

I have done PCA for 21 images of the same person in different conditions. LAst step of the PCA is projection of original data : signals=PC'*data.                                                                          Size of signals is 21*21, now I want to write this to a CSV file with a label as +1. Please guide me how to do this in matlab. I tried csvwrite but it does not write the labels, only the data.

Comment: Please post the code you used for csvwrite. I would suggest you create two files, one for the data and the second for the labels. But it's hard to tell what you want without seeing an example.

Comment: @Sid, I know you won't believe me, but you really really don't need to write your data to a file. Assuming this is directly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850344/libsvm-data-preperation

Comment: @Donda : i have the data in a .mat file, so should i just load the .mat file? But then how do i obtain the training_label_vector and training_instance_matrix? Sorry i am not understanding how to pass data without writing to a file.

Comment: @Dan : I got the output using- csvwrite('filename',[labels signals]); Signals from a previously saved csv file and i defined labels in the same code as the above mentioned csvwrite.

Comment: @Sid Post your code then...

Answer (score 0):

```
    [signals,V]=pca(im2double(inputdata));                                                                                              
    for i=1:length(signals)                                                
       for j=1:1
           label(i,j)=+1;
    end(both for)
csvwrite('f1.csv',[label signals]);
```